# Ruby, is there a built in method to split an array into two sub arrays at a specified index?

Tags: ruby

Doing a ruby problem and thinking to myself, there must be an easier way.

I want to split an array at a specified index into two sub arrays. The first sub array containing the numbers up to the specified index, and the second sub array containing the numbers after and including the specified index.

Example

```
([2, 1, 2, 2, 2],2) => [2,1] [2,2,2]
#here, the specified index is two, so the first array is index 0 and 1, 
the second is index 2, 3, and 4. 

def array_split(arr,i)
  arr1 = []
  arr2 = []
  x = 0

  while x < arr.count 
    x < i ? arr1 << arr[x] : arr2 << arr[x]
    x += 1
 end 

 return arr1, arr2
end
```

This was no issue with a while loop. I want to know if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is :)

```rb
arr1 = [2, 1, 2, 2, 2].take 2 #=> [2, 1]
arr2 = [2, 1, 2, 2, 2].drop 2 #=> [2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I was hoping for a single line that returns an Array of 2 Arrays so you could do `arr1, arr2` assignment, but comparing the alternatives, this seems like a cleanest and clearest method, without creating a custom method to do it. Thanks.

Comment: You can split an array in half with Rails' [Array#in_groups](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups) method (or sized groups with `in_groups_of`), though blindly ingesting information from an array in this way implies likely code smell and it's worth evaluating whether the solution is brittle or solving the wrong problem

Answer (score 1):

```
def split a, i
  [a[0...i], a[i..-1]]
end

p split [2,1,2,2,2], 2

# here is another way

class Array
  def split i
    [self[0...i], self[i..-1]]
  end
end

p [2,1,2,2,2].split 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is also `values_at` which can take single items, items at different positions, and ranges of positions:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a.values_at(1,3)
# => [1, 3]
a.values_at(3..7)
# => [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```